# Why, postive root is choosen in expressing inverse sine in terms of natural logarithm

Tags: complex-analysis, logarithms

**Question**: As seen in underlined part of below attached picture: [image]

$±\sqrt{1-z^2}$ is implied by $\sqrt{1-z^2}$ **But how?** **what this means?**

**Why they considered only positive root?**

**My attempt**: let's try by considering negative root!

Say $e^{iw}=iz-\sqrt{1-z^2}$ then,
By taking natural logarithm on both sides we get,

$iw=\ln(iz-\sqrt{1-z^2})$

$w=\frac{1}{i}\ln(iz-\sqrt{1-z^2})$

Hence if we put $z=0$, then we get,

$w=\frac{1}{i}\ln(-1)$

as logarithm function is not defined for negative numbers, hence we see that,$w=\sin^{-1}z$ will not be defined at $z=0$

But we have $sin^{-1}(0)=0$ hence we must consider, positive root!

**Is am I correct?**

Further, **is considering negative root is wrong? What we get by considering negative root?**

Please help...

Comment: Which book is this taken from?

Comment: Pic: from complex variable by  'Schaum's outlines'

Comment: Since we are working in the complex numbers, [$\ln(-1)=i\pi$](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=ln%28-1%29). This leads to the wrong branch of $\sin^{-1}$, but it's defined.

Comment: @DavidK sir, so is my attempt is not correct? Further, what's the reason they considered only positive root? and what is underlined part in picture means?

Comment: I don't know what they mean by the underlined part. Maybe it is how they get the right answer for the wrong reason. Just looking at the typesetting, this book was put together without much care for detail.

Comment: @DavidK sir, so what's the answer of this question? Why they considered positive root? is considering negative root is wrong? and what we get by considering negative root? Please help

Comment: Your description of "positive root" makes no sense.  Remember we are working in the complex plane here and $\sqrt{}$ is to be interpreted as a branch of square root, so $\pm\sqrt{1-z^2}$ can be replaced with $\sqrt{1-z^2}$ with the understanding that I haven't specify which branch of $\sqrt{}$ I am taking.

Comment: @user10354138 That's one possible interpretation (vs. $(1-z^2)^{1/2}$ for the general root and $\sqrt{1-z^2}$ for the principal branch), but if we take that interpretation then the answer is incomplete because we were supposed to write the formula for one branch of $\sin^{-1}$ and instead we have a formula for all branches.

Comment: @DavidK The branch is chosen only at the very end of the image when you substitute $z=0$.

Comment: @user10354138 Selecting a value of $k$ doesn't select the branch of $\sqrt{1-z^2}$. But suppose we say that in the end we stealthily replace the general root $\sqrt{1-z^2}$ with the principal branch of $\sqrt{1-z^2}$. How then would we find the formula for the branch of $\sin^{-1}$ such that $\sin^{-1} = \pi$?